# Почему в объекте __proto__, который содержит функция-конструктор.prototype, нужно указывать prototype после точки?

Tags: javascript, конструктор, prototype

Такой вопрос. Почему если какой-либо объект был создан с помощью функции-конструктора, то в `__proto__` он обязательно будет содержать `функция-конструктор.prototype`?

```js
function NewObj() {};

let a = new NewObj;
console.log(a.__proto__ == NewObj.prototype); //true
```

Какой практический смысл в указании `prototype` после точки? Спрашиваю это, потому что вроде бы как... `prototype` функции-конструктора содержит единственное св-во `constructor`, которое в свою очередь содержит ссылку на эту же функцию-конструктор. Так вот, в чем смысл фактически 2 раза подряд ссылаться на одну и ту же функцию-конструктор?

Почему, например, такая запись выдает `false`?

```js
function NewObj() {};

let a = new NewObj;
console.log(a.__proto__ == NewObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewObj.prototype` обычно используется как хранилище данных или методов, общих для всех экземпляров, созданных конструктором. Этот `NewObj.prototype` автоматически назначается прототипом создаваемых экземпляров, в котором по цепочке прототипов ищутся свойства, отсутствующие непосредственно в экземплярах. То есть, хоть по умолчанию там есть только свойство `.constructor`, туда можно добавить что угодно. Обычно это работает так:

```js
function NewObj() {};

NewObj.prototype.foo = 42;

let a = new NewObj;
let b = new NewObj;

console.log(a.foo); // 42
console.log(b.foo); // 42
```

Подробности см., например, в этих разделах: https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes